# Показать картинку через обработчик

Tags: php, изображения, img

Добрый вечер, хочу чтоб картинки на сайте открывались через обработчик, например так:
http://yiiframework.ru/forum/download/file.php?avatar=5301_1377506680.png

как реализовать такое?

Пробовал по разному:
пишу в img src через гет передаю названия картинки, а в обработчике просто пробовал через echo "обсалютный url до картинки", ноль результата, пробовал менять контент тип `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` тоже ноль(

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
echo '<img src="/images/'.$_GET['avatar'].'" alt=""/>';
```

Не знаю что у вас там. Но у меня прекрасно работает.

UPD: так бы сразу и сказали.

код вывода

```
<?php
echo '<img src="file.php?avatar=image.png" alt=""/>';
```

код файла file.php

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
readfile($_GET['avatar']);
```

Comment: Ну да, если отдельно открыть в браузере то работает и у меня тоже а если указать этот урл в src то нет. Я хочу, как здесь http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18699 сделаны отображения аватара <img src="http://yiiframework.ru/forum/download/file.php?avatar=5301_1377506680.png">

Comment: >Я хочу, как здесь

Зачем вы сознательно хотите сделать плохо?

P.S. Нет, я не хочу сказать, что "там" - плохо. У них могут быть свои соображения. Но исходить нужно из того, что без достаточной мотивации и внятных обосований такой способ - заведомо плох.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Я пытаюсь через обработчик изменить прямой урл к картинке таким образом т.е. если настоящий урл images/name.jpg то после обработчика например newurl/newname.jpg.

Comment: @rnddev, спасибо за помощь!